# Rearranging levels of a nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, data-structures

Is there a library that would help me achieve the task to rearrange the levels of a nested dictionary

Eg: From this:

```
{1:{"A":"i","B":"ii","C":"i"},2:{"B":"i","C":"ii"},3:{"A":"iii"}}
```

To this:

```
{"A":{1:"i",3:"iii"},"B":{1:"ii",2:"i"},"C":{1:"i",2:"ii"}}
```

ie first two levels on a 3 levelled dictionary swapped. So instead of 1 mapping to A and 3 mapping to A, we have A mapping to 1 and 3.

The solution should be practical for an arbitrary depth and move from one level to any other within.

Comment: Did you ever find a nice solution?

Comment: For the 2-level case: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43391661/1896169

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> d = {1:{"A":"i","B":"ii","C":"i"},2:{"B":"i","C":"ii"},3:{"A":"iii"}}
>>> keys = ['A','B','C']
>>> e = {key:{k:d[k][key] for k in d if key in d[k]} for key in keys}
>>> e
{'C': {1: 'i', 2: 'ii'}, 'B': {1: 'ii', 2: 'i'}, 'A': {1: 'i', 3: 'iii'}}
```

thank god for dict comprehension

Answer (score 6):

One way to think about this would be to consider your data as a (named) array and to take the transpose. An easy way to achieve this would be to use the data analysis package Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({1: {"A":"i","B":"ii","C":"i"},
                   2: {"B":"i","C":"ii"},
                   3: {"A":"iii"}})
df.transpose().to_dict()

{'A': {1: 'i', 2: nan, 3: 'iii'},
 'B': {1: 'ii', 2: 'i', 3: nan},
 'C': {1: 'i', 2: 'ii', 3: nan}}
```

Comment: A good option, but this only works if the values of your dictionary can be read into pandas.

Comment: Elegant, but pollutes your new dict with nan's (still really like it).

Answer (score 0):

I don't really care about performance for my application of this so I haven't bothered checking how efficient this is. Its based on bubblesort so my guess is ~O(N^2).

Maybe this is convoluted, but essentially below works by:
- providing dict_swap_index a nested dictionary and a list. the list should be of the format [i,j,k]. The length should be the depth of the dictionary. Each element corresponds to which position you'd like to move each element to. e.g. [2,0,1] would indicate move element 0 to position 2, element 1 to position 0 and element 2 to position 1.
- this function performs a bubble sort on the order list and dict_, calling deep_swap to swap the levels of the dictionary which are being swapped in the order list
- deep_swap recursively calls itself to find the level provided and returns a dictionary which has been re-ordered
- swap_two_level_dict is called to swap any two levels in a dictionary.

Essentially the idea is to perform a bubble sort on the dictionary, but instead of swapping elements in a list swap levels in a dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict
def dict_swap_index(dict_, order):
    for pas_no in range(len(order)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(pas_no):
            if order[i] > order[i+1]:
                temp = order[i]
                order[i] = order[i+1]
                order[i+1] = temp
                dict_ = deep_swap(dict_, i)
    return dict_, order

def deep_swap(dict_, level):
    dict_ = deepcopy(dict_)
    if level==0:
        dict_ = swap_two_level_dict(dict_)
    else:
        for key in dict_:
            dict_[key] = deep_swap(dict_[key], level-1)
    return dict_

def swap_two_level_dict(a):
    b = defaultdict(dict)
    for key1, value1 in a.items():
        for key2, value2 in value1.items():
            b[key2].update({key1: value2})
    return b
```

e.g.

```
test_dict = {'a': {'c': {'e':0, 'f':1}, 'd': {'e':2,'f':3}}, 'b': {'c': {'g':4,'h':5}, 'd': {'j':6,'k':7}}}
result = dict_swap_index(test_dict, [2,0,1])
result
(defaultdict(dict,
             {'c': defaultdict(dict,
                          {'e': {'a': 0},
                           'f': {'a': 1},
                           'g': {'b': 4},
                           'h': {'b': 5}}),
              'd': defaultdict(dict,
                          {'e': {'a': 2},
                           'f': {'a': 3},
                           'j': {'b': 6},
                           'k': {'b': 7}})}),
 [0, 1, 2])
```