# How to switch the nesting structure of a dictionary of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

If I have the following dictionary:

```
dict_a = {'a': {'x': 0, 'y': 1, 'z': 2},
          'b': {'x': 3, 'y': 4, 'z': 5}}
```

What is the best way to switch the structure of the dictionary to:

```
dict_b = {'x': {'a': 0, 'b': 3},
          'y': {'a': 1, 'b': 4},
          'z': {'a': 2, 'b': 5}}
```

Comment: It's better to clarify if you need to handle non complying data.

Comment: Is the dictionary always **two levels deep**?

Comment: Yes, always two levels

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## With default dictionary

Given the dictionary is always two levels deep, you can do this with a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict_b = defaultdict(dict)

for k,v in dict_a.items():
    for k2,v2 in v.items():
        dict_b[k2][k] = v2
```

Which gives:

```
>>> dict_b
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'x': {'a': 0, 'b': 3}, 'z': {'a': 2, 'b': 5}, 'y': {'a': 1, 'b': 4}})
>>> dict(dict_b)
{'x': {'a': 0, 'b': 3}, 'z': {'a': 2, 'b': 5}, 'y': {'a': 1, 'b': 4}}
```

`defaultdict` is a subclass of `dict`, you can turn the result again in a vanilla `dict` with `dict_b = dict(dict_b)` (as is demonstrated in the second query).

## With pandas

You can also use `pandas` for this:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

dict_b = DataFrame(dict_a).transpose().to_dict()
```

This gives:

```
>>> DataFrame(dict_a).transpose().to_dict()
{'y': {'a': 1, 'b': 4}, 'x': {'a': 0, 'b': 3}, 'z': {'a': 2, 'b': 5}}
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't need `defaultdict` to transpose the nested dict if we use [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```py
def transpose(nested_dict):
    result = dict()

    for x, nested in nested_dict.items():
        for a, val in nested.items():
            result.setdefault(a, dict())[x] = val

    return result
```