# Python pull data from string

Tags: python, python-requests

I have the following string of data:

```
{"responseStatus":"ok","responseHeader":{"now":1528734419187,"status":"ok","requestId":"Wx6i0wquZS4AAFNeStwAAABg"},"responseData":{"id":38}}
```

and I need to pull the "id":38 out of it and format it a "id":"38"

Comment: This isn't a string at all, it's a `dict`, but if not you should probably just use `json.loads` on it and treat it like a normal `dict`

Comment: You have a dictionary, not a string pf data. So, just use dictionary indexing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rearranging levels of a nested dictionary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33425871/rearranging-levels-of-a-nested-dictionary-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you're using the `requests` library (based on your tag), when calling your repsonse, instead of returning `.content`, you can return `.json()`:

```
response = requests.get(....).json()
response['responseData']['id'] = str(response['responseData']['id'])   # or you can just do "38"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `json` module:

```
import json
json_s = json.loads('{"responseStatus":"ok","responseHeader":{"now":1528734419187,"status":"ok","requestId":"Wx6i0wquZS4AAFNeStwAAABg"},"responseData":{"id":38}}')

json_s['responseData']['id'] = '38' # Or str(json_s['responseData']['id'])


print(json_s)
```

Or in this case it is a valid dictionary so you could use `eval()`:

```
json_s = '{"responseStatus":"ok","responseHeader":{"now":1528734419187,"status":"ok","requestId":"Wx6i0wquZS4AAFNeStwAAABg"},"responseData":{"id":38}}'

a = eval(json_s)

a['responseData']['id'] = '38' # Or str(a['responseData']['id'])

print(a)
```

If you want to convert the dictionary in `json_s` and `a` back to a string then just use `str(json_s)` and `str(a)` respectively.

See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) for the use of `eval()`.

Otherwise to keep away from `eval()` use the `ast` module.  As described here:

[Convert a String representation of a Dictionary to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary)

Comment: `eval()` is evil and really shouldn't be used unless absolutely necessary. also, their question is how to change the value of a key, but there's no mention of how to do so in your answer.

Comment: @crookedleaf Thank you.  I've fixed my answer.